# How exactly do files get opened from Nautilus?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, .desktop

I am asking this out of curiosity, to know what goes on 'behind the scenes' when I double click a file in a file browser, say Nautilus. Specifically, what parameters is the executable executed with? Where does the .desktop file come into play, and how does Nautilus send the filename?

This was relevant to me once when Okular would open multiple instances of the same file, and I had to write a shell script, which used to fail because the filename didn't get passed properly. (Spaces in the filenames would get converted into an HTML %20 character, and I had to figure out a lot how exactly filenames are passed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two directories that contain `.desctop` files: `/usr/share/applications/` (global list for all users) and `~/.local/share/applications/` (for a particular user). Both directories contain a list of file type associations (`defaults.list` and `mimeapps.list` correspondingly).

When you click a file, Nautilus finds the appropriate `.desctop` file and launches your program. Each `.desctop` file contains the `Exec` key which specifies the command line (the program and its parameters). See [this document](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) for details on the `Exec` key.

If a `.desctop` file specifies a program without the full path, it will be looked up on your `$PATH`. In a default installation, `$PATH` usually includes the following directories: `/usr/local/sbin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, `/sbin`, `/bin`.

Comment: Thanks! And what happens if both .desktop files are removed? Will it ask me to select which program to open it with?

Comment: I have just created a binary file with no content type specified in it, and with a random extension (`.ttt`). I tried to open it in Nautilus. I got a `The file is of an unknown type` message, and there was a button for selecting one of the registered programs there. I think, if you remove any associations for a particular content type, something similar will happen :)